# How do I perform 100% daily water changes when fridging an axolotl?

Tags: amphibians, water-changes

I'm planning on fridging my axolotl as he keeps floating for extended periods after eating. I have read extensively how to fridge so I feel confident to do it, but I was just wondering how is best to perform the 100% daily water changes.

He will be in a Tupperware in the fridge and I'm planning to keep dechlorinated water in there too for the water changes. I also wondered how long is best to fridge him for, do I just do it until he stops floating?